# ALAsset module for Titanium works on simulator but crashes on device any hints?

Tags: titanium-modules

I forked this great Titanium module to access the ALAsset.
https://github.com/amigoni/titanium-mobile-alasset-module

I am trying to access the pictures data and info. It seems to work fine in the simulator but not on the device.

Here is where I suspect the code is

```
-(void)assetThumbnails:(id)args
{
ENSURE_UI_THREAD_1_ARG(args);
ENSURE_SINGLE_ARG(args,NSDictionary);

id onthumb       = [args objectForKey:@"thumbnailCallback"];
NSString *group = [args objectForKey:@"group"];
ENSURE_STRING_OR_NIL(group);
int page        = [TiUtils intValue:[args objectForKey:@"page"] def:1] - 1;
int perPage     = [TiUtils intValue:[args objectForKey:@"perPage"] def:25];

int fromIndex   = page * perPage;
int toIndex     = fromIndex + perPage;

NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos;
if( group == nil ){
    group = @"savedPhotos";
}
if( [group isEqualToString:@"savedPhotos"] ){
    groupTypes  = ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos;
} else if( [group isEqualToString:@"photoStream"] ){
    groupTypes  = ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream;
} else if( [group isEqualToString:@"faces"] ){
    groupTypes  = ALAssetsGroupFaces;
} else if( [group isEqualToString:@"all"] ){
    groupTypes  = ALAssetsGroupAll;
}
NSMutableArray *assets  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
RELEASE_TO_NIL(thumbCallback);
thumbCallback  = [onthumb retain];
void (^assetGroupEnumerator) (ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
    if(group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if( result != nil )
            {
                if( (index >= fromIndex) && (index <= toIndex) ){
                    NSURL *url = [[result defaultRepresentation] url];
                    NSString *sUrl = [url absoluteString];
                    NSDictionary *metadata = result.defaultRepresentation.metadata; 
                        UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
                        NSDictionary *event = [NSDictionary 
                                               dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               [[[TiBlob alloc] initWithImage:thumbnail] autorelease],
                                               @"thumbnail",
                                               NUMINT(index),
                                               @"index",
                                               sUrl,
                                               @"url",
                                               metadata,
                                               @"metadata",
                                               nil];
                        [assets addObject:event];
                }
            } else {
                if (thumbCallback!=nil)
                {
                    NSDictionary *event = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:assets,@"assets", nil];
                    [self _fireEventToListener:@"onThumbnail" withObject:event listener:thumbCallback thisObject:nil];
                    [assets release];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
};

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {}];
[library release];
}
```

What's interesting is that the code seems to crash after the 26th item. Which as you see from the code above would be the first of the second page.

I really don't know much about Objective C and was looking for some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [release assets] raises an exception. My case is that.

On allocating assets, [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease] and remove the line;
The exception will not raise.